# Get zip code from latitude/longitude

Tags: mysql, location

I have a control that allows a user to either enter a zip code or open up google maps in an iframe and click on the map to pick a location. I currently have this all working and the iframe will send the lat/lon from the click event back to the parent.

I also have a db table set up with lat/lon fields mapped to zip codes.

However, the lat/lon combination will most likely never exactly match the entry I have in the db. So, I'm looking for the best way to match the closest zip code.

Because the user has the ability to manually enter the zip code, I'm not totally worried about precision(i.e. if a user clicks on a border between zip codes), but I would like it to be close as possible. I only need to worry about US locations for now.

My current idea for a solution is to come up with some tolerance(.2?) and query the db for the lat/long +- the tolerance. Then pick the closest match from the result set.

I'd love to hear from someone who has done this before or has a better solution than the one I proposed. I'm not interested in using a service as I have all the data I need.

One concern I have with my proposed solution is figuring out what a good tolerance would be. This project is targeted for rural areas and I'm not sure how spread out the lat/lon entries for these areas could be.

Edit: Here is my table structure:
zip5 | city | state | lat | lon | county

zip5 is the primary key

Comment: May I ask why you are you trying to convert lat/lon to zipcode? Once you have the lat/lon you have the key to finding  other entities by their proximity. What does having the zipcode get you that having a lat/lon doesn't get you?

Comment: @Tim According to the design spec I was given, the zip is to be displayed in the html input. I could argue against it, but this doesn't seem like it should be that difficult.

Comment: If you need to find the distance between 2 sets of lat/lon, google Greatest Circle Distance ... Then you can easily calculate the distance from the given zip code (lat/lon) to the ones you have on file ...

Comment: But you will have to use something like R-trees or some analogous approach to limit the query to only the set of nearby zips, or you will have to measure the distance to all of them and pick the nearest.

Comment: @dleiftah: `the ones you have on file`.  What if you have ALL zipcodes on file?

Comment: Indeed I have all zipcodes as I am using them in the opposite direction as well. Showing lat/lon on the map based on a user's zip. I would really like to filter most of the data with a query and avoid running distance formulas on 40000+ entries

Comment: Well, if you're starting with ONLY a lat/lon pair, what data structures do you have in place, if any, that would allow you to eliminate all but the small set of nearby candidate zips?  Can you get the State from the lat/lon?  Can you get the county from the lat/lon? Do you have state-zip linking tables? County-zip linking tables? R-tree-zip linking tables?  Having to return the zipcode from the lat-lon takes a lot of preparation for the query not to involve a full-table scan of 40,000 zips.

Comment: I edited the post with my table structure

Comment: The zipcode is for human consumption and irrelevant except insofar as it gives the human a warm-and-fuzzy feeling.  Your discussion of 'tolerances' is an analog for R-trees.   You need some way to divide the map into a grid and to link each grid cell to the zipcodes it touches. so you can quickly go from from lat-lon to grid cell to touching-zipcodes to closest zipcode (centroid).

Comment: Hmm this is very interesting. Although probably not practical for me unless I can find this data set already put together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical solution to this problem uses R-trees.

Comment: From the reading I have done I agree with you. Unfortunately I'm not sure how I would create bounding boxes for all zip codes.

Comment: A bounding box can be of any size and it can be defined by its top left and bottom right coordinates. Let's say you made boxes 25 x 25 miles.  You would create your table of bounding boxes.  Then you would iterate your bounding boxes table, and then in a nested loop iterate your zipcode table and compute whether the centroid of the zip fell within the box. If it did, you create a boundingbox-zipcode link in the link table.  At runime you compute which bounding box the click occurs in, select its linked zips, and compute the distance to each, selecting the nearest.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. Hopefully my zip table's lat/lon fields are the centroid and this will be even easier.

Answer (score 2):

One minute of Latitude (ie 1/60 degree) = 1 n.m., or about 6,000 feet. Therefore 5 min. Latitude = about 30,000 feet  = about 6 statute miles.

Longitude narrows towards the poles, but if we take the continental US as being about 36 degrees North, give or take (a fair bit I agree, but an approximation should be suficient for this application), then one minute of Longitude ~ 1 n.m. * cos 36 ~ 6,000 * 0.81 = 4,850 feet.

Since Zip codes (or at least the first set of 5 digits) represent post offices, which in rural areas are likely 20-30 miles apart, you could do worse than to use a Lat-Long grid of about 1/2 that, or say 10 min. Latitude x 12 min. Longitude. Those are conveniently 1/6 degree and 1/5 degree respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful response. It seems like those values could very well be a decent tolerance to work off of.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to ditch your own database lookup and use a webservice that already does this, such as [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html).  See the SO question [Get zip code from latitude, longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564852/get-zip-code-from-latitude-longitude/3565614#3565614) for more info.  Looks like it already does what you're trying to do, but without all the calculations and tolerances.

Comment: I specifically wrote in my question that I am not interested in a service. I have everything I need to make this work, I just need to be able to filter most of the data with a query.